# .zip three futures in Scala

Tags: scala

I need the `result` variable below to contain `Future[(String,String,String)]` with the result of futures `f1`, `f2` and `f3`, but instead I'm getting `Future[((String, String), String)]`. I need the three futures to run in parallel. How to make this work?

```
  def futureA = Future { "A" }
  def futureB = Future { "B" }
  def futureC = Future { "C" }

  def futureFunc = {

       val cond1 = 1
       val cond2 = 0

       val f1 = if (cond1 > 0) 
             futureA
       else 
             Future {""} 

       val f2 = if (cond2 > 0) 
             futureB
       else 
             Future {""} 

       val f3 = futureC

       val fx = f1.zip(f2)

       val result = fx.zip(f3)

  }
```

Comment: Please, try to understand the answers to the questions you already asked (possibly by asking for more details), instead of asking multiple variants of the same basic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create more solutions and here is result:

```
  def futureFunc = {

    val cond1 = 1
    val cond2 = 0

    val f1 = if (cond1 > 0)
      futureA
    else
      Future {""}

    val f2 = if (cond2 > 0)
      futureB
    else
      Future {""}

    val f3 = futureC
//#1
    Future.sequence(List(f1, f2, f3)).map {
      case List(a, b, c) => (a, b, c)
    }
//#2
    for{
      f11 <- f1
      f22 <- f2
      f33 <- f3
    } yield (f11, f22, f33)
//#3
    f1.zip(f2).zip(f3).map{
      case ((f11,f22),f33) => (f11,f22,f33)
    }

  }
```

First one uses Future sequence, for creating Future[List[]] and then mapping this list for tuple (because of type safety we don't have method for tupling list).

Second is usage of for comprehension as described by Sascha, as you may know it is syntactic sugar for maps and flatmaps which is preferred to work with futures.

Last one is using zips, as you wanted, but you still need to map last future to obtain tuple which you want.

All operations are non blocking, but for all operations you need to know exactly futures which you will be using. You can use additional libraries for tupling lists, and then use first solution for not well known amount for futures. For readability i think for comprehension is best.

Comment: for comprehension runs the futures in parallel or sequentially?

Comment: for comprehensions is syntactic sugar for maps, as you can see higher, Futures starts running as soon as you create them. In your code you can assume that futures are completed while declared, because you tried to run only creating String in new thread (i assume that you know that most of your futureFunc will work sequentially). So for comprehension will map all promised values into tuple, and when all futures (which runs in parallel from the time when you created them) will be completed you then can obtain (str,str,str) values from your Future. Is that clear for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you create your futures beforehand, you can combine them in a for comprehension and they will run in parallel:

```
for {
  a <- f1
  b <- f2
  c <- f3
} yield (a, b, c)

res0: scala.concurrent.Future[(String, String, String)]
```

Comment: using for comprehension doesn't run the futures in parallel

Comment: afaik, a future is started as soon as you create it. This is why I used f1, f2, f3 which are `val`s in your code.

Comment: Correct, as long as the futures aren't `lazy val`s or `def`s, this **will** execute them at the same time